# gstreamer setup problems on windows

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cmake, gstreamer

The farthest I came was the error that a procedural entry point (don't know about the exact wording, since weirdly this message was in german, although my system is in english: "Prozedureinsprungspunkt") couldn't be found for:

- FT_Done_MM_Var in the harfbuzz.dll
- opj_codec_set_threads in the gstopenjpeg.dll

**installation:**
I used `gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.18.0.msi` and `gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.18.0.msi` from the standard [gst download site](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/).

**environmental variables:**

1. added / set `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` to `GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_MSVC_X86_64`, since I had prior problems with simple plugins like "playbin" being unknown.
2. added `GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_MSVC_X86_64/bin/` to `PATH` for the dll's

**cmake setup:**
I wrote an ugly, but simple [FindGSTREAMER.cmake](https://pastebin.com/h8qENyMB) which is used in my [CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/WMc2A0XG). The libraries and include paths are added accordingly for the targets.

**source code:**
I am only compiling the gstreamer ["HelloWorld"](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=c) so far for testing.

I generated the solution for vs2019. Gstreamer can be found and it compiles. Problems are the above mentioned runtime errors / i dont see the video I am supposed to see.
I also have warnings/errors in the console that I wanted to pipe into a file for this question. The .exe is weirdly placed inside `build/src/{Debug / Release}/` directory and if I execute it from command line I am again not linking to the dll's, so I executed it from the gst binary directory.... the bummer is it works if I execute it from there.
So what do I need to change so that it also works from visual studio and don't have to execute from the gst binary directory?

**EDIT:** Forgot the [console output](https://pastebin.com/yvfvWuuw), which to me felt like more of the same "can't load modules".

**UPDATE:** So this isn't really a fix, but a work-around and observation. I used the according gst methods to create pipeline and elements, which only worked, when executed from gstreamer's binary directory like stated in my question. Recently I tried to build my own pipeline explicitly defining which demuxer, parser and decoder to use. This worked fine while experimenting with `gst-launch-1.0` but when in code with `gst_element_link` the link between demuxer and parser failed. So I switched to `gst_parse_launch` and it worked. Not only the linking but now it also executes from visual studio directly... I honestly don't know why, but it is a neat work-around for now.

Comment: Are the paths (*D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc\_x86\_64\bin*) from the warnings correct? Are **all** the files in the warnings there? Can you post the path for your *.exe* and *.dll*s? If you open a *cmd* window, it works without setting any *env vars*? In that window what does `where harfbuzz.dll` output?

Comment: `D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin` is the binary directory to the installation location of gstreamer. So I believe it is correct, if I need to link to the `bin` of gstreamer for the dll's. The _.exe_ I build is on the same drive: `D:\Programming\gstreamer_lib` and then described like in my question.  I don't set any more _env vars_ than described in my question. `where harfbuzz.dll` prints the same location from the _.exe_'s directory and gst's binary directory: `D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\harfbuzz.dll`